# why am I getting "non-aggregate cannot be initialized with initializer list"

Tags: c++, xcode

```
std::map<std::string, int> m = {
    {"Marc G.", 123},
    {"Zulija N.", 456},
    {"John D.", 369}
};
```

In Xcode I have C++ Language Dialect set to "C++0x [-std=c++0x]" and C++ Standard Library set to "libc++ LLVM C++ Standard library with C++0X Support"

Do I need to set something else?

Comment: Syntax seems correct with or without the '=' (assuming you brought std::string in scope of course).

Comment: `g++ -std=c++11 <filename>`

Answer (score 43, accepted):

**EDIT 10/2013**: this answer is really old, Apple Clang does support this now.

C++11 Initializer Lists are not yet supported as of Clang 3.0

See the implementation status here: [Clang C++11 implementation status](http://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html)

(Your syntax looks correct if only the compiler supported this feature)

Comment: Oh, I thought it depended on the library used. I guess it makes more sense that the compiler needs to support it.

Comment: You might try using GNU++11 (-std=gnu++11). Pretty sure it supports initializer lists.

Comment: -std=gnu++11 worked for me - was difference compiling in Xcode or from makefile

Comment: Why does this not work using -std=c++11 on clang3.4? I haven't read the standard, but I don't think return list initialization is an extension...

Comment: Is there an alternative for pre-c++-11 array initialization?

Comment: If using Eclipse, properties, C/C++ Build, Settings, GCC C++ Compiler, Dialect, Language standard, you can select ISO C++11 (-std=c++0x). This was on a MacAir macOS 10.13 Eclipse Oxygen 3a c++ 4.2.1 clang 900

Answer (score 28):

Clang 3.6.2 supports initializer-list syntax. Just remember to pass `-std=c++11` flag when compiling.