# Initialising Vectors with Clang++

Tags: c++, macos, clang++

I found a similar question here [why am I getting "non-aggregate cannot be initialized with initializer list"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8920699/why-am-i-getting-non-aggregate-cannot-be-initialized-with-initializer-list) but the answer says it works now, which it doesn't seem to for me. The code:

```
vector<int> temp = {1,2,3,4,5};
```

And the error I recieve:

```
test.cpp:18:14: error: non-aggregate type 'vector<int>' cannot be initialized
with an initializer list
vector<int> temp = {1,2,3,4,5};
```

When I try:

```
clang++ --version
```

I get:

```
Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.40) (based on LLVM 3.4svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.2.0
Thread model: posix
```

So is the last thread correct and it should work now or am I making a mistake in compilation?
Thanks.

Comment: It's a C++11 feature.

Comment: In other words, compile it like this: `clang++ -std=c++11 program.cpp`. Of course, you could add other flags as well.

Comment: @red_eight doesn't work on High Sierra

Comment: @xxks-kkk I just tested it with High Sierra. It worked for me.

Comment: @red_eight you're right. I made some mistake in my code that leads to false alert. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

The default C++ Clang standard is C++98, which doesn't support vectors, so just provide a newer version.

Example:

```
clang++ main.cpp -std=c++11
```

Comment: This depends on the version of Clang/LLVM - e.g. Clang 16 defaults to C++17.