# C++ Eclipse Neon : non-aggregate type 'string' cannot be initialized with an initializer list

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-neon

I am getting the error message

```
non-aggregate type 'string' (aka 'basic_string<char, char_traits<char>, allocator<char> >') cannot be initialized with an initializer list
```

While using below as a global variable in my C++ code at Eclipse Neon.

```
string boardStr = {". . . . . . . . B . . . L L L . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .",
        ". . . . . . . . B . . . L L L . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .",
        ". . . . . . . . B . . . L L L . . . L L L . . . . . . . . . . .",
        ". . . . . . . . B . . . L L L . . L L L . . . R R . . . . . . .",
        ". . . . . . . . B . . . L L L L L L L L . . . R R . . . . . . .",
        ". . . . . . . . B . . . L L L L L L . . . . . . . . . . . . . .",
        ". . . . . . . . B . . . . . . . . . . . . R R . . . . . . . . .",
        ". . . . . . . . B B . . . . . . . . . . . R R . . . . . . . . .",
        ". . . . . . . . W B B . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .",
        ". . . R R . . . W W B B B B B B B B B B . . . . . . . . . . . .",
        ". . . R R . . . W W . . . . . . . . . B . . . . . . . . . . . .",
        ". . . . . . . . W W . . . . . . . . . B . . . . . . T . . . . .",
        ". . . W W W W W W W . . . . . . . . . B . . . . . . . . . . . .",
        ". . . W W W W W W W . . . . . . . . . B . . R R . . . . . . . .",
        ". . . W W . . . . . . . . . . B B B B B . . R R . W W W W W W W",
        ". . . W W . . . . . . . . . . B . . . . . . . . . W . . . . . .",
        "W W W W . . . . . . . . . . . B . . . W W W W W W W . . . . . .",
        ". . . W W W W W W W . . . . . B . . . . . . . . . . . . B B B B",
        ". . . W W W W W W W . . . . . B B B . . . . . . . . . . B . . .",
        ". . . W W W W W W W . . . . . . . B W W W W W W B B B B B . . .",
        ". . . W W W W W W W . . . . . . . B W W W W W W B . . . . . . .",
        ". . . . . . . . . . . B B B . . . . . . . . . . B B . . . . . .",
        ". . . . . R R . . . . B . . . . . . . . . . . . . B . . . . . .",
        ". . . . . R R . . . . B . . . . . . . . . . . . . B . T . . . .",
        ". . . . . . . . . . . B . . . . . R R . . . . . . B . . . . . .",
        ". . . . . . . . . . . B . . . . . R R . . . . . . . . . . . . .",
        ". . . . . . . . . . . B . . . . . . . . . . R R . . . . . . . .",
        ". . . . . . . . . . . B . . . . . . . . . . R R . . . . . . . .",
        ". . . . . . . . . . . B . . . . . . . . . . R R . . . . . . . .",
        ". . . . . . . . . . . B . . . . . . . . . . R R . . . . . . . .",
        ". . . . . . . . . . . B . . . . . . . . . . R R . . . . . . . .",
        ". . . . . . . . . . . B . . . . . . . . . . R R . . . . . . . ."};
```

Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8920699/why-am-i-getting-non-aggregate-cannot-be-initialized-with-initializer-list) post, I updated the compiler settings as below attached image

[image]

Still see the error. What am I missing? I am on Mac OSx El Capitan.

Comment: Do you want a `string` or a `string` array?

Answer (score 6):

Here's a shorter example:

```
std::string fails{ "abc", "def", "ghi" };
```

There is no such [constructor for `std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) that takes a bunch of string literals.

But you don't need that anyway. You really are just trying to construct your `string` from one big literal. And string literals can be concatenated - just remove your commas:

```
std::string ok{ "abc" "def" "ghi" };
std::string also_ok = "abc" "def" "ghi";
```