# C++ Standard Template Library simple code giving error in vs code in macos mojave

Tags: c++, templates, stl, linker-errors

I am working in STL in c++ in the vs code editor and i have declared an array as given in the code below...

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    vector<int> arr={11,2,13};
    for(int i=0;i<3;++i)
    cout<<arr[i]<<" ";
    return 0;
}
```

I am getting the error that non-aggregate type vector cannot be initialized with an initialiser list.
When i compiled the code in Clion ide, it works fine.
So what is the problem in vs code?

Comment: Visual studio code is just an ide, which compiler are you using and what arguments are you passing to it

Comment: i have a macbook air 2017 running macos mojave 10.14.5 and i am using the compiler that comes with xcode

Comment: i have also used the c++ extension for vs code to write c++ codes in vs code

Comment: *and i am using the compiler that comes with xcode* -- And what compiler is that?  Also what compiler are you using with VS Code?  You need to know the underlying tools that are actually being used to build your program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the compiler does not support c++11.

you can use `-std=c++11` and try again.

eg. `g++ -std=c++11 -c example.cpp`

And also can get more info form this [why am I getting “non-aggregate cannot be initialized with initializer list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8920699/why-am-i-getting-non-aggregate-cannot-be-initialized-with-initializer-list)

Comment: Yes, when i use any c++ 11 feature, the code editor gives me warning that this feature is a part of c++ 11...

Comment: Is there any way to set it to c++ 14 directly for always in vs code?

Comment: @DhruvBansal Maybe you need to set up your compile command with C++ 14 feature. So sorry for that, I was no more experience with vs code.