# visual studio code problem with running c++

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm starting programming in c++ and I wanted to setup my VSC to be able to run and debug code in c++. I was following many tutorials how to do it and it still doesn't work. I'm getting this
error: non-aggregate type 'const vector<pair<int, std::string> >' (aka 'const vector<pair<int, basic_string<char, char_traits, allocator > > >') cannot be initialized with an initializer list
const vector<pair<int, string> > rzym = {
^      ~

Everything works in Xcode but on VSC not when i run it in terminal it also doesn't work can someone help me solve this problem. I'm using mac m1 chip

I basically followed this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KhGnYWplLVo and also https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp

Answer (score 0):

If you can edit your post to include your code, there may be more we can do to help. But in the mean time, it sounds like it may be related to [this post where a similar issue was seen between xcode and vscode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8920699/why-am-i-getting-non-aggregate-cannot-be-initialized-with-initializer-list).